# How to get the max value in c#

Tags: c#

I have this pretty simple C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i, pcm, maxm = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your computer marks");
        pcm = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I would like to get max value for the var pcm, how could I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just keep track of it!

For each iteration, if the entered number is greater than the number that you have in `maxm`, then set `maxm` equal to the current entered number.

At the end, you'll have the maximum.

Pseudocode:

```
max = 0
for three iterations
  get a number
  if that number is more than max
    then set max = that number
```

Comment: +1 for the clear explanation and pseudocode instead of just typing a code solution. Nice use of an educational opportunity. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just another alternative to the posted ones.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var numbers = new List<int>();

   for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Please enter your computer marks");
       numbers.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
   }

   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Maximum value: {0}", numbers.Max());
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the typed in value in the `maxm` variable. If the user types a larger number, then you replace that value:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i, pcm = 0, maxm = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your computer marks");
        pcm = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // logic to save off the larger of the two (maxm or pcm)
        maxm = maxm > pcm ? maxm : pcm;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The max value is: {0}", maxm));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: An explanation (without copy/paste code) would probably have been a better choice here. It looks like a homework question. (Not downvoting; just commenting.)

Answer (score 0):

I would try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i, pcm, maxm = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your computer marks");
        pcm = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if(maxm <= pcm)
        {
             maxm = pcm;
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's another solution that uses Linq.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i, pcm, maxm = 0;
    List<int> vals = new List<int>();
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your computer marks");
    pcm = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    vals.Add(pcm);
    }
    maxm = vals.Max(a => a);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```